# Blocking a specfic DMR ID

Tags: repeater, callsign, station-identification, dmr

Is it possible to block a specific DMR ID Rx, sort of "ignore"?

If so, is it repeater-based, or it has to be set locally, on radio?

Speaking of popular md380/390 radios, there is a "Call Alert" feature on Contact list, but didn't find any information regarding that feature, or how it's supposed to work. Any intel on that?

73

Comment: so, this question is specific to the Tytera MD380, or is it general?

Comment: DMR in general, regardless of radio. Does such feature even exist?

Comment: well, if DMR in general, we cannot talk about device features but must look at protocol logic. And since that protocol has a specification that says that transmissions must have a callsign, yes, that is a feature that is *possible* for a device to have. (because if the device can distinguish calls by originating callsign, there's nothing stopping them from **not** notifying the user)

Comment: well, I wish I could tell you that I knew whether devices *do* have that feature :) That's the downside of DMR being proprietary: In a world were communication standards are open, there'd be a lot of ease in adding such a feature to a device.

Comment: Totally agree :) Such custom mods are possible, then. That's what I needed to know. Virtual upvotes for the comments, because I'm still unable to give them ;) 73

Comment: So, it took a lot of good work by Travis Goodspeed KK4VCZ to reverse-engineer the MD-380 so that he implement a "promiscous" mode on it, to have the first DMR "scanner" (which ironically is kind of the opposite of what you want). If DMR was an open standard, we'd be swimming in software implementations letting us all do *exactly* what we want with it. But no, we prefer to pay license fees to the IC manufacturers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55194/discussion-between-yt5zec-and-marcus-muller).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any radio firmware that would support blocking a specific ID.

It would be easy to implement in MMDMHost.

Call Alert is a ringer function. If a radio receives a call alert signal then it rings and sends back an answer to the caller and the caller radio shows a message about the successful delivery.